# Power BI Rest API OData Package

Tags: rest, powerbi, odata

I am trying to create an application using Power BI Rest API. The data returned from Power BI is in the form of OData structure. Just wonder where I can download the data structure classes in C#?

Answer (score 0):

We've done that for you by publishing the [.NET PowerBI Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerBI.Api/) on NuGet.